# Overriding a DatagramSocket file from android.jar while emulating android on eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, overriding

I'm trying to inject a network failure on my DatagramSocket.java file from the android.jar lib. However, I've been trying to build it on a Vbox with ubuntu since last sunday (4 days) unsucessfully. 
I'm wondering if there is any way how to inject MINE DatagramSocket.java without needing to build the android.jar, like Configure Build Path (Eclipse) and add a file that overrides another existing?

Does someone knows if it is possible?
thanks in advance and sorry about my english. It's not my native language

Diego

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this for testing, you might want to look at Robolectric for substituting alternative implementations of Android classes, or use a mocking framework like EasyMock or jMock.